# Make mod_rewrite pass multiple parameter

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to write url-rewrite in php need make such url store/{stre-name}?offer=10 for Example see below

```
/stores/mango?offer=10

/stores/apple?offer=10
```

i have write .htacess as

```
RewriteRule ^stores/(.*)$ offer.php?c=$1&offer=$2 [L]
```

and write code on offer.php as

```
$c = $_GET['c'];
$offer = $_GET['offer']
```

i have got value of c here successfully , but i have not got value of offer here . So please help me how can i read the value of offer in offer.php

```
RewriteRule ^stores/(.*)$ offer.php?c=$1&offer=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Maybe: `RewriteRule ^stores/([^?]+)\?offer=(.*)$ offer.php?c=$1&offer=$2 [L]`

Comment: @AbraCadaver this not working for me  i have write                   RewriteRule ^stores/(.*)\?offer=(.*)$ offer.php?c=$1&offer=$2 [L]  and got error Object not found!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rewrite **/store/mango/?offer=10** to **/offer.php?c=mango** with the old queryString, You need to use QSA flag in your rule that combines new and old queryStrings

```
RewriteRule ^store/(.+)/?$ /offer.php?c=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you.

```
      RewriteRule ^store/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /offer.php?c=$1&offer=$2 [L]
```

You can try also for make SEO friendly URL

```
      RewriteRule ^store/([^/]*)?([^/]*)\.html$ /offer.php?c=$1&offer=$2 [L]
```

Comment: this is working for url  "/stores/apple/?offer=10"                                                         But i want such url :  /stores/apple?offer=10 So plz help me for this url mod_rewrite

Answer (score 0):

This code is working for me:

```
RewriteRule ^stores/(.*)?([^/]*)$ offer.php?c=$1&offer=$2 [QSA,L]
```

For this URL:

```
/stores/mango?offer=10
```